# How do I use dictionary to replace long if else block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing an income tax calculator for 2017. Right now for calculating Federal taxes I have a long if else block:

```
def taxes(income):
    """Calculate income tax brackets from 10% to 39.6%"""
    if 0 < income <= 9325:
        return income * 0.1
    elif income <= 37950:
        return 932.5 + .15 * (income - 9325)
    elif income <= 91900:
        return 5226.25 + .25 * (income - 37950)
    elif income <= 191650:
        return 18713.75 + .28 * (income - 91900)
    elif income <= 416700:
        return 46643.75 + .33 * (income - 191650)
    elif income <= 418400:
        return 120910.25 + .35 * (income - 416700)
    else:
        return 121505.25 + .396 * (income - 418400)
```

I found in some other posts that I can use dictionary to access the values directly with `dict.get(key, default)`. But in my case it's a bit different since I'm comparing `income` in a range of tax brackets and doing calculations with the income. Is there a way for me to use dictionary to simulate the if else block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using lambda functions and the thresholds in your if-else statements, you could do:

```
TAX_DICT = {
    0:        lambda income: income * 0.1,
    9325:     lambda income: 932.5 + .15 * (income - 9325),
    37950:    lambda income: 5226.25 + .25 * (income - 37950),
    91900:    lambda income: 18713.75 + .28 * (income - 91900),
    191650:   lambda income: 46643.75 + .33 * (income - 191650),
    416700:   lambda income: 120910.25 + .35 * (income - 416700),
    418400:   lambda income: 121505.25 + .396 * (income - 418400)
}

def taxes(income):
    for threshold in sorted(TAX_DICT)[::-1]:
        if income >= threshold:
            return TAX_DICT[threshold](income)
```

You could also create a regular function for each threshold instead of a lambda function.

Comment: Using a `dict` here makes no sense, if you are simply going to iterate over it. You might as well just use a list of tuples and avoid the sort. This is totally over-engineered and needlessly inefficient. The if-else *is a better way of doing this*. If your number of intervals were huge, you could consider using some sort of binary-search based approach.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer!  Would like to see a method using a list of tuples since I happen to be doing a similar task at the moment.

Comment: I mean just use `[(418400, lambda income: 121505.25 + .396 * (income - 418400)), (416700, lambda income: 120910.25 + .35 * (income - 416700)), ...]` Anyway, I wouldn't add that as an answer because it would still be over-engineered. Anyway, if you create a dictionary only to immediately iterate over it, then you probably shouldn't be using a dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The list-of-tuples approach does have the advantage that you *know* each case behaves the same way.  If you write an if/elseif/else statement with seven branches, how sure are you *really* that each comparison operator is a `<=`, that the variable on the LHS of each is `income`, etc.?  The human brain can only check so much before it starts seeing what it expects rather than what's actually there...

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries work by taking all the possible hashcodes that values could have and dividing them up into buckets. When you want to look something up they hash it, check in the appropriate bucket, and see if there's something there.

This approach isn't going to work here, because if you look up a number like 100,000 the dictionary won't know to look under the hash value of 91,900 in particular.

What you want instead for this class of problem is a sorted collection of tuples that you can perform a binary search on.  If the list is going to change at runtime this should be some kind of self-balancing binary tree; if not, it can just be a pre-sorted array.

In your case since there are only a few items, doing a binary search is probably more trouble than it's worth; just walking through the list should be fine.